# XGBoost Regressor same prediction values issue

Tags: time-series, prediction, xgboost

I am trying to make a comparison between several different methods and only on XGBoost and Random Forest I am having the issue of same prediction value for the test period. Data is USA Consumer Price Index data and there is a clear increasing trend only (no seasonality). Below is the part of my code:

```
train = df\[df\['ds'\] \< '1990-01-01'\]
test = df\[df\['ds'\] \>= '1990-01-01'\]

xgb_model = xgboost.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000,
learning_rate=0.01,
max_depth=6,
min_child_weight=1,
colsample_bytree=0.8,
objective='reg:squarederror',
reg_alpha=0.1,
reg_lambda=1.0
)

xgb_model.fit(np.arange(len(train)).reshape(-1, 1), train\['y'\])
xgb_forecast = xgb_model.predict(np.arange(len(train), len(train) + len(test)).reshape(-1, 1))

print(xgb_forecast)
\[125.38897 125.38897 125.38897 125.38897 125.38897 125.38897...
...125.38897 125.38897\]
```

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Thanks a million in advance!

I tried to make a time series forecasting, I expected XGBoost machine learning method to catch the increasing trend but it only outputted constant prediction values.